# jQuery - How to detect mouse is not over #a and #b

Tags: jquery

Html code

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="box"></div>
```

How can i check if the mouse is not over #a & #b and then run the function

```
$("#a").mouseleave(function () {
$("#box").fadeOut(800));
});
```

Comment: which function you want to run ?

Comment: I hope $("#a && #b").mouseleave(function () {....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to keep a "cache" of whether the mouse is in A or B, and finally you need to check whether both are in the "out" state and then run your `fadeOut` function. A word of warning, allow the user a few milliseconds to transition from one to the next, otherwise you'll find it doesnt work as expected.

This code should do it, with a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jzCjD/

```
var inArr = {a:false,b:false};

$('#a, #b').mouseover(function(){
    inArr [$(this).attr('id')] = true;
});


$('#a, #b').mouseout(function(){
    inArr [$(this).attr('id')] = false;

    setTimeout(function(){ 
          if(!inArr.a && !inArr.b) 
              $('#box').fadeOut(800) 
    },100);
});
```

Comment: Woo!very great,I never consider about "cache" on jquery,thank you so much Jamiec!

Answer (score 2):

like this:

```
$("#a, #b").mouseout(function () {
   $("#box").fadeOut(800);

});
```

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XWRZF/)

Answer (score 2):

you can check here http://jsfiddle.net/XWRZF/2/

```
var myTimer = false;

$("#a ,#b").hover(function(){
    //mouse enter
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
},function(){
    //mouse leav
  myTimer = setTimeout(function(){
         $("#box").fadeOut(800);
    },100)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them in a parent div and replace #a in your code with #parent-div:

```
<div id="parent-div">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
<div id="box"></div>


$("#parent-div").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#box").fadeOut(800));
});
```

Otherwise, if you need the divs to be separate, the cache solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

The `mouseleave` and `mouseout` events are triggered only after a `mouseover` or `mousein` event, which actually means that in order to detect if the cursor is hovering an element using these events, you must first be hovering it so that the events would be triggered.
The right way to do this is to bind an event handler to all the mouse movement in the document and check the event's target :

```
var elements = $('#a, #b');
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    if(elements.get().indexOf(e.target) != -1)
        // you're over a or b
});
```

This way you don't have to hover an element in the first place in order to trigger `mouseout` or `mouseleave` events.
Here's a live demo :

### http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/NLjjq/

Answer (score 0):

In case you were looking for a simple if statement.

```
if ( !$("#a, #b").is(":hover") ) {
    // not on it!
}
```

You still of course need to bind this if to an event of some kind, you may decide to do:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    //the snippet from above
});
```

Comment: Best Answer, simple and effective!